# Interactive image in React

Tags: reactjs

I have an idea on project where all f1 track are described.
In My vision i want to make interactive map of tracks, when user mouseOver on any number on picture, should popup modal with description. Track should look like this :
[image: PaulRiccard]

I don't know how to start, my React skill is very basic but this project should learn me a lot :) Can You help me and describe a little how can I make this component with interactive track ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the area tag to define the coordination you want a script runs. This is not something React specific I think it is best to handle it with HTML tags.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The map and area elements</h1>

<p>Hover mouse over the computer to see the alert</p>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" width="400" height="379">

<map name="workmap">
  <area onmouseenter="myEnterFunction()" shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" href="coffee.htm">
</map>
<script>
    function myEnterFunction(){
        alert("Hello\nHow are you?");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

- you can do it with this React library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@overlapmedia/imagemapper it includes a demo: https://overlapmedia.github.io/imagemapper/examples/browser/index.html. It will allow you to further develpment (zoom in-out, tooltips, etc)
- or if you want, you can use this jQuery plugin  (recomended) http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/
- or using SVG vector images (recomended option if it will be a big project)
- or natively with only html and css: https://matemarschalko.medium.com/interactive-image-maps-and-closable-popups-with-html-and-css-only-31fe36c70092